# BIRT Report JSON array printed values

Tags: javascript, java, json, birt

I'm trying to print out JSON values from a database column into multiple lines in my Birt report. It prints the last line of the JSON array just fine, but not the lines before it.

My code for my dynamic text field:

```
var phone = JSON.parse(row["c_numbers"]);
for(var k in phone) {
    phone[k]['type']+': '+phone[k]['phone']
}
```

This is what it prints:

[image]

And here is the JSON from the database:

```
[{"type": "Cell", "phone": "123-123-1233"}, {"type": "", "phone": "123-423-4123"}]
```

Easiest would be just to print it out, but it's not doing more than the last array item. Report design:

[image]

So it's getting the data, iterating over the JSON, and printing, but not all array items, only the last one.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I did, with the json above. You can take that json and put into into a BIRT report and run it to test. I cannot provide our RPTDesign file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to assign the new data to a new variable, then print out that final variable at the end. I also had to add `<br>` for a newline at the end of each output.

```
var phone = JSON.parse(row["c_numbers"]);
var finalPhone = '';

for(var k in phone) {
    finalPhone = finalPhone+(phone[k]['type'] > '' ? phone[k]['type']+': ' : '')+phone[k]['phone']+"<br>"
}

finalPhone;
```